# What does "Mrs" mean when used with a man's name?

Tags: abbreviations, names, titles, surnames, natural-gender

As far as I know, the abbreviation "Mrs" is applicable only to women.
Though, when translating an article from an old British paper I found this sentence about marriages:

> On the 2nd March, at the British Embassy, Paris, LIEUTENANT GENERAL NAPIER CAMPBELL to CAROLINE MARGARET DUFF (**Mrs.** HENRY PRICHARD), daughter of the late Deputy Surgeon-General Charles Murray Duff

Can anyone tell me what "Mrs" means in this context? As I understand it, Henry is only a male given name.
I thought that maybe this is just the person conducting the marriage, but this discrepancy between "Mrs" and the name confuses me.

Comment: If the source is the simulation boardgame "Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective" then perhaps you should say so

Comment: Not sure I agree with the edit made to the title here. The original "Usage of Mrs for male" made it clear that the person asking is a non-native speaker. Secondly, it's clearer why the question is being asked, "Why does a male have a female title?". Thirdly, the older title was snappier and *quirkier*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA IMO the new title is a better explanation/summary of *what* is being asked (at the expense of explaining why it was asked, which the previous title also didn't do well ). The why is still apparent if you read the body text of the question.

Comment: In the book Great Expectations, the main character's sister's first name is never mentioned. She is only said as Mrs. Joe Gargery. There's a lot of old-timey stuff in there that makes it confusing as hell.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> - ***Mrs*** was most often used by a woman when married, in conjunction with her husband's first and last names (e.g., Mrs John Smith).
> - A widow was and still is addressed with the same title as when she was married. *Mrs* was rarely used before a woman's first name, her maiden name, or a hyphenated surname her husband was not using. For example,  *Mrs Jane Miller (wife of John Smith), Mrs Jane Smith, or Mrs Jane Miller-Smith were considered incorrect by many etiquette writers, especially of the early 20th century.*

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs.#Traditional_usage)

Comment: This anachronism is still practised by the All England Lawn Tennis Club, commonly known as Wimbledon. Their [Ladies Singles Honour Roll](http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/roll_of_honour/ladiessingles.html) lists 2006 finalist Justine Henin-Hardenne under her then husband's name, *Mrs. P-Y Hardenne*. And in 1980 there was an all-wives final between *Mrs. R.A. Cawley* (Evonne Goolagong Cawley) and *Mrs. J.M. Lloyd* (Chris Evert-Lloyd).

Comment: And couples were also known as Mr. & Mrs. John Smith.

Answer (score 25):

Josh61 is 100% right, however, I would like to point out that even today, in formal circumstances especially, it's still custom and valid to address a wife as Mrs. *[Husband Name]*.

My wife goes by:

- Heather Cotey - 70% of the time (the default)
- Mrs. Heather Cotey - In communication that relates to just her but is slightly formal
- Mrs. Robert D. Cotey II - In any communication that relates to her, formally, as the female head of the household. (Matron, Mother, Wife)
- Mr. And Mrs. Robert D. Cotey II - In any formal communication that relates to both of us in just about any way.

I don't think we have been introduced, formally, as Robert and Heather Cotey at any time. Though, in less formal settings, we have been introduced as:

- Heather and her husband, Robert
- Robert and his wife, Heather
- Robert and Heather
- The Coteys - When in a casual family orientated setting.
- Mr. and Mrs. Cotey - This is most common, non-formal, non-personal introduction (think business or similar where you're not being friendly)

It's important to note that these days it has a lot to do with the circles you run in and how you present yourself. Just in general, I am usually called Mr. Cotey by nearly everyone I do business with. My wife is Mrs. Cotey. When conducting business, it's rare that we go by our first names. When hanging out with friends and family, Heather and Robert are pretty common.

Point being that the usage you listed is still in use today, and you may run into it again. Especially in formal situations.

Comment: Re etiquette and names (in the US). Professionally, women almost entirely now go by Ms. TheirGivenFirstName TheirLastName. (and TheirLastName is what they were born with or by choice if they married possibly their husbands last name). For wedding invitations (the most formal situation nowadays), there is a lot of variation: If married, Mr & Mrs Bobby Watson _or_ Mr Bobby and Mrs. Suzy Watson, if not but both appearing... it gets complicated.

Comment: It does, a lot of it is preference, opinions, and audience.

Comment: Just to add coteyr and Mitch 's answer/comments also 100% apply in the UK ( apart from the ' II ' thing, which is definitely a US-only usage, but obv. not the point of the answer)

Comment: @peterG Tell that to Elizabeth II. :)

Comment: @Mitch: it is more a matter of convenience.  I know a woman who uses her husband's name at work (for pronunciation/ethnic discrimination reasons) but her birth surname at home (for cultural reasons)

Comment: @reirab OK you got me there! :-)

Comment: While it's still certainly in use, the reception you get will vary significantly depending on your audience. There are many (particularly professional, particularly younger) women who would actively take offence to being referred to as Mrs Husbandsname even in the most formal situations. I would not address a woman I didn't actively know preferred that address as Mrs Husbandsname. (Mrs Cotey or Mrs Heather Cotey seem much more neutral to me.)

Comment: Maybe edit a caveat into your answer? As folks have pointed out in comments, this might work for some people, but it sounds archaic and possibly offensive to others - I don't think I'd describe that as "still custom and valid."

Comment: @krman - See my post about how when it's just her it's Mrs. Heather Cotey, when it's addressing her as the female head of the family, then it's Mrs. Robert Cotey. 99% of the time you would address her as her and not as head of the family. Not many people address the family unit as a whole anymore. A topic for another SE though.

Comment: It doesn't seem so hard to figure out when John marries Jane and James marries June, but what do you when John marries James and Jane marries June? Calling people by other people’s names seems quite confusing.

Comment: @tchrist It probably depends who wears the trousers in the relationship. But traditional usages tend to sit uneasily in non-traditional contexts, so I expect each couple will come up with something. A new tradition will have emerged in a couple of hundred years' time.

Answer (score 3):

Mr. John Smith is the husband, while Mrs. John Smith is the wife.

However, this usage has fallen by the wayside over time, as females were recognized as people and not property, got the right to vote and own land, etc.

Similarly, while Master John Smith is used for a male child, and Miss Jane Smith is used for an unmarried female of any age, the current usage tends toward "Ms." for both married and unmarried females.

Times change, and English usage changes over time to reflect that.

Comment: This answer lacks references and examples, but otherwise seems about right to me. The downvotes seem a bit unnecessary; unless something's changed in the edit.

Comment: I believe the downvotes are because this answer seems to project modern, progressive values onto the customs of historical periods and/or to show bias against modern traditionalists.

Comment: @JHCL It seems unnecessary to get up on a soapbox about the backwardness of this usage or society in the past when that is not really what the question is about.  Sure, it's reasonable to say that today many women would be offended by being addressed in this way, but this answer goes beyond that into pontificating and jumbling together various societal changes taking place over a wide span of time.

Comment: My down vote at least is due to the soap boxing. It also makes a statement that using Mrs. Husband's name is some how sexist (an opinion presented as a fact) without any facts to back it up.

Comment: My downvote is due partly to the false claim that the appellation "Mrs. John Smith" was used to label women as property, when there is no evidence of any particular motive behind this practice. Also, as Josh61's and coteyr's answers demonstrate, the idea that it has "fallen by the wayside" is false as well. It is certainly less common than it once was, but it is still proper in certain contexts.

Comment: Just because you don't like something doesn't mean that it doesn't exist or that it was common english usage. There are still areas of this planet where women have zero rights and are treated like property.. Women's rights are  relatively new in even the Judo-Christian societies of North America and Europe."Upon marriage, the husband and wife became one person under the law, as the property of the wife was surrendered to her husband, and her legal identity ceased to exist" .Married Womens Property Rights Act enacted 1882 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Married_Women%27s_Property_Act_1882

Comment: Calling a woman by the form Mrs. John Smith is proper only if the woman consents to be called that.  And fewer of us do than 50 years ago.